# Antifreeze Boiling/Bubbles

Tags: dodge, smoke, coolant-reservoir, avenger

Ok so the problem I'm having that started a few days ago is after driving for about 10 minutes or so my 2010 Dodge Avenger starts to smoke and the temperature needle raises to overheat. BUT when I turn on the heat it cools down. When I check under the hood the reservoir is boiling. I've had the problem for over a year off and on but the reservoir has NEVER boiled nor have the car actually smoked. I took it to Landers in December and the said they could not replicate the problem but replaced the water pump, thermostat and thermostat housing. However the problem persisted. A few days ago coming from work after I got home I noticed the engine cap had been BLOWN OFF and what I believe to be oil was everywhere. I've replaced the oil and the coolant but I still am having my initial problem. Any ideas? Google is pointing towards a blown gasket.

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Answer (score 1):

[image]
Check radiator cap, too. Defective one on the right is missing the black seal in the center. This caused overheating and a buildup of pressure.

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicles Maintenance & Repair!  Could you [edit your question](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/posts/55395/edit) to expound on why a bad radiator cap would cause pressure buildup and overheating?  Otherwise good answer!  I like the pictures.

Answer (score 0):

Well, first I think your coolant boiling issue could be due to not having any pressure in the system - either the cap was not sealing or it was broken or, possibly there was a small leak - did it require topping up at all...

For the second issue of you cap, you say it had "blown off" but is it possible that someone had topped up the oil and not replaced the cap? This could lead to oil getting everywhere...

Comment: I did flush it and top it off but that didn't help. And the cap had actually blown off, I'm sure of it.

Answer (score 0):

could be a blown head gasket..have or do a compression test to see if there is a low cylinder or 2 also can be a bad radiator ie: clogged veins...could also be a clogged converter causing back pressure to over heat the head and cause a blown gasket....have the radiator removed and flo checked at any radiator shop to verify it's ability to do its job...the converter have checked at a muffler shop